# My picture wont show on my github website do anybody know?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a picture show on my GitHub website, but it isn't showing up.

It only shows this:

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
<img src="C:\Users\amund\Downloads\Amund5.png" alt="Amund5"src="Amund5.png" width="500" height="400">
```

I tried changing the script but it didn't work

Comment: `C:\Users\amund\Downloads\Amund5.png` is a path on your local machine's file system. It is not going to be the same path for GitHub, because the computers serving GitHub have their own file system/s. You will need to upload the image as an asset for your web app, in a relative path to your index page. So instead of the absolute path that you gave, you'll want a relative path such as `./public/img/Amund5.png`. However, we can't say for certain how to fix this because you haven't provided any code or details regarding your web app.

Comment: And even if you want to access a local file on the client machine, that's not the correct URL syntax. It would be `file:///C:/Users/amund/Downloads/Amund5.png`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Answer (score 1):

---

Your `img src` refers to a path on your local machine.  So while `amund5.png` is at `c:\Users\amund\Downloads` on your machine, that's not where Github is going to find it.

You'll need to commit the image to your repository, then reference its location relative to the repository. You can also use a fully-qualified URL, like `<img src="https://my.site/some-path/Amund5.png">`

Answer (score 0):

Loading from local resources is not allowed. There are a few workarounds for this:

1. Upload the image to the repository itself and index it from there

```html
<img src="./Amund5.png" alt="Amund5" />

<!-- file structure -->
├── Amund5.png
├── index.html
```

2. Upload the image to some online service like **Google Photos** or **Imagur** and use the image link in the `img` tag

```html
<img src="https://example.com/imgs/Amund5.png" alt="Amund5" />
```